# How to control number of processes in GaussianMixture

Tags: python, performance, scikit-learn, parallel-processing

There are no `n_jobs` parameter for [GaussianMixture](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture.html#sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture.score). 
Meanwhile, whenever I fit the model

```
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture as GMM
gmm = GMM(n_components=4,
          init_params='random',
          covariance_type='full',
          tol=1e-2,
          max_iter=100,
          n_init=1)
gmm.fit(X, y)
```

it spans 16 processes and uses full CPU power of my 16 CPUs machine. I do not want for it to be doing that.

In comparison, [Kmeans](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html) has `n_jobs` parameter that controls mutliprocessing when having multiple initializations (`n_init` > 1). Here multiprocessing comes out of the blue.

My question is where its coming from and how to control it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are observing parallel-processing in terms of basic algebraic operations, speed up by [BLAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Linear_Algebra_Subprograms)/[LAPACK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAPACK).

Modifying this is not as simple as setting a `n_jobs` parameter and depends on your implementation in use!

Common candidates are ATLAS, OpenBLAS and Intel's MKL.

I recommend checking which one is used first, then act accordingly:

```
import numpy as np
np.__config__.show()
```

Sadly these things can get [tricky](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31622299/2320035). A valid environment for MKL for example can look like this [(source)](http://www.diracprogram.org/doc/release-12/installation/mkl.html):

```
export MKL_NUM_THREADS="2"
export MKL_DOMAIN_NUM_THREADS="MKL_BLAS=2"
export OMP_NUM_THREADS="1"
export MKL_DYNAMIC="FALSE"
export OMP_DYNAMIC="FALSE"
```

For ATLAS, it seems, you define this at [compile-time](http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/faq.html#tnum).

And according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23585680/2320035), the same applies to OpenBLAS.

As OP tested, it seems you can get away with setting environment-variables for [OpenMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP), effecting in modification of behaviour even for the open-source candidates Atlas and OpenBLAS (where a compile-time limit is the alternative):

```
export OMP_NUM_THREADS="4";
```

Comment: Wow. I checked active BLAS library being used by numpy and then setting variable with `export OMP_NUM_THREADS="4";` before running the script did the trick. Thank you so much!

Comment: @tarashypka And which one is in use? MKL? Or did this even work for some of the other candidates?

Comment: Output is something like this `libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']`